# SQL Server Bulk Insert from UNC location returning no records and no errors

Tags: csv, format, sql-server-2016, unc, openrowset

I have a CSV file on a network drive that I want to load using bulk insert in a stored procedure in SQL Server. This CSV file has record delimiters like "text1","text2" etc. The file has a total of 27 columns and approximately 90 rows.

I have created the following format file that matches the input file:

[image: Format File]

When I copy the csv to the server and run the Bulk Insert - it works fine and returns all the records as expected.

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK N'K:\Upload\Shipping\testship.csv',
                 FORMATFILE = 'K:\Upload\Shipping\shipping.fmt',
                 FIRSTROW = 2) j
```

However, the same does not return any records if I source the file from a UNC.

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK N'\\servername\Marketing\SHIPPING\Vessel_Departures_and_Cut-off\5Aug.csv',
                 FORMATFILE = '\\servername\Marketing\SHIPPING\Vessel_Departures_and_Cut-off\shipping.fmt',
                 FIRSTROW = 2) j
```

This returns 0 records with just the column headers. No errors even when I specify a error log file!

It's not a permission issue on the network location as I do the same with other files and they work fine (but they don't have record delimiters hence no format file!)

Can someone shed light on why this might be please?

UPDATE:

I had copied the csv from UNC to local. when I compare the two files (from the unc and from the local) Notepadd++ says they are encoded differently! Could be a hint why the UNC files are not loading. How do I specify encoding please? How would I know what encoding to use?

If I open the original file with Notepad ++, copy all the contents into a new file and save it, I can successfully load the new file! What gives!

Comment: Have you  verified you can actually read ths file from the network without a format file eg with `SINGLE_CLOB`. Have you remembered to copy the format file to the network location? Have you tried pointing to the local format file?

Comment: @Stu Yes, I've tried SINGLE_CLOB and it only returns the header row and not the data. Yes, I've tried copying the format file to the network location where the csv resides and have the same issue - No rows returned. Yes, I have tried pointing the format file to a local copy and still the same! Using SINGLE_CLOB on a local file returns only the header record!

Comment: UPDATE : SINGLE_CLOB on a local files returns all the data as a single row
Using the same on the same file on a UNC return just " and nothing else.

Comment: Have you checked the file encoding? There's no `CODEPAGE` specification in your openrowset. Also what happens if you try using a text odbc driver eg `'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0'`

Comment: @stu I've added an updated section to my question. Re Encoding!